# Dropdown Data Binding Problem in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC

Tags: data-binding, asp.net-core-mvc, dropdown, asp.net-core-6.0

I am using `SelectListItem` in the controller for binding my dropdown data. All the dropdown options are showing perfectly in the dropdown list, but when I try to save, the problem occurs. It's not adding the dropdown options data rather than its adding dropdown data's id.

All the related models, controller and views are shown here:

`BuyerSelectList` model class:

```
public class BuyerSelectList
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("BUYER")]
    public string Buyer { get; set; }
}
```

`ItemSelectList` model class:

```
public class ItemSelectList
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("ITEM")]
    public string Item { get; set; }
}
```

`BTBNewLien2` model class:

```
public class BTBNewLien2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Buyer")]
    public int BuyerSelectListId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BuyerSelectListId")]
    [ValidateNever]
    public BuyerSelectList BuyerSelectList { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Item")]
    public int ItemSelectListId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ItemSelectListId")]
    [ValidateNever]
    public ItemSelectList ItemSelectList { get; set; }
}
```

`BTBNewLien2` controller (here I added all the data binding functionalities for my dropdown):

```
namespace CommercialCalculatorWeb.Areas.Admin.Controllers
{
    public class BTBNewLien2Controller : Controller
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

        public BTBNewLien2Controller(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<BTBNewLien2> objBTBNewLienList = _unitOfWork.BTBNewLien2.GetAll();
            return View(objBTBNewLienList);
        }

        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            BTBNewLien2 btbNewLien2 = new();

            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> BuyerSelectList = _unitOfWork.Buyer.GetAll().Select(
                c => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = c.Buyer,
                    Value = c.Id.ToString()
                });

            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ItemSelectList = _unitOfWork.Item.GetAll().Select(
                c => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = c.Item,
                    Value = c.Id.ToString()
                });

            ViewBag.BuyerSelectList  = BuyerSelectList;
            ViewBag.ItemSelectList = ItemSelectList;

            return View(btbNewLien2);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Create(BTBNewLien2 obj)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _unitOfWork.BTBNewLien2.Add(obj);
                _unitOfWork.Save();
                TempData["success"] = "Row Created Successfully!";
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

`BTBNewLien2` create view:

```
@model CommercialCalculator.Models.BTBNewLien2

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>BTBNewLien2</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row ml-6">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="BuyerSelectListId" class="control-label">Buyer</label>
                <select asp-for="BuyerSelectListId" asp-items="ViewBag.BuyerSelectList"  class="form-control">
                    <option disabled selected>--Select Buyer--</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ItemSelectListId" class="control-label">Item</label>
                <select asp-for="ItemSelectListId" asp-items="ViewBag.ItemSelectList"  class="form-control">
                    <option disabled selected>--Select Item--</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

`BTBNewLien2` index view:

```
@model IEnumerable<CommercialCalculator.Models.BTBNewLien2>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sm align-middle m-0" id="header">
                        <tr class="m-0" style="text-align:center;background-color: #17A2B8">
                            <th width="20%">
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BuyerSelectList)
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ItemSelectList)
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        @foreach (var BTBNewLien2 in Model)
                        {
                            <tr class="m-0">
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => BTBNewLien2.BuyerSelectList)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => BTBNewLien2.ItemSelectList)
                                </td>
                                
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way：

`@Html.DropDownList("ItemSelectListId", new SelectList(ViewBag.ItemSelectListId, "Text", "Text"), "-- Select Item --", new { required = true, @class = "form-control" })`

In my code, it works fine：

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Create()
{
    List<SelectListItem> test = new()
    {
        new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "test1" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "test2" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "test3" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "4", Text = "test4" }
    };

    ViewBag.ItemSelectListId = test;
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(Test test)
{
    return View();
}
```

View:

```
<div class="row ml-6">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ItemSelectListId" class="control-label">Buyer</label>
                 @Html.DropDownList("ItemSelectListId", new SelectList(ViewBag.ItemSelectListId, "Text", "Text"), "-- Select Item --", new { required = true, @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Test Result:

[image]